# Identify Portuguese Tree

Tags: identification, trees

**Can anyone help me identify this particular tree?**

It grows at least in Portugal (north and south).
This branch is obviously dry.

Many thanks

[image: unknown tree]

Comment: I think it would be very helpful if you could post a photo of the actual tree, with any other details you may have, such as whether it flowers, what colour they are and so on

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be a *Tamarix*, e.g. *Tamarix africana*: it grows on souther Portugal and near the costs in northern Portugal. See http://www.florestar.net/tamargueira/tamargueira.html.
But I find no good pictures of branches, so I cannot verify.

It remember me also a lot the *Callistemon*, see e.g. the picture in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bottlebrush_seeds.jpg, but it is not native of Portugal.

Comment: Thanks! While the seed does look a lot like the Callistemon, the pictures I found online of the Tamarix rank it as a very likely match. My grandmother had a couple on her house, unfortunately a decade or so ago a block was built there and all trees removed so I can't get an actual photo of the tree. Your input was amazing!

Comment: It is Melaleuca orophilla the Needle Bottle brush.